# mule 4 payload inside java

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule4

I need to access the mule 4 payload inside java code in my mule application.

my payload is a complex json (nested json) with many fields so I cannot create a function with many parameters.

what is the best way of doing that.

my java code is invoked using the java-invoke component (the class/method are not static).

my java function looks like the following:

```
public class MyClass {
 
public static void main(String args[]) {
}

public void myMethod(Object payload) {
//do some stuff with payload
}
}
```

my payload as mentioned is a complex json like below

```
{
  "time": "2022-01-02T11:11:11",
  "name": "satish",
  "app" : "appname",
  childJson: {
    "key1": "val1",
    "key2": "val2"
},
"anothersubjson: {
    "key1": "val1",
    "key2": "val2"
    "key3" : [{a: "a", b: "b"}]
}
}
```

my mule code to invoke java is below

```
<java:new class="com.me.MyClass"
    constructor="MyClass()"
    target="myClassVar"/>

<java:invoke instance="#[vars.myClassVar]"
  class="com.me.MyClass"
  method="myMethod(Object)"
  target="response">
      <java:args>#[{data: payload
      }]</java:args>
</java:invoke>
```

Comment: Have you tried just sending the payload as the parameter? Did you have any issues? What have you tried? What is the criteria to use for "best way"? As you are probably aware that kind of open ended questions could lead to opinion based answers.

Comment: And what do you want to with the JSON payload in the Java code?

Comment: What have you tried to pass the payload yet?

Comment: ammending my question

Comment: What the issue or result when you try that code?

Comment: method is expecting java.lang.object but you are passing linkedhashmap (if I set a transform before and convert to java). and you are trying to pass byte stream if i set it as json itself.

Comment: A LinkedHashMap is actually a java.lang.Object, as any other Java class inherits from Object. Why exactly a map is not useful for your use case? What exactly were you expecting instead is not clear.